# Cannot assign value of type [Page] to type [StudyPage]?

Tags: swift3, model

I have a study model and a studyList model, but I can't assign the pages array of Study model  to Studypage array of Studylist model

```
func didLoadData(studies: [Study]){
        for item in studies{
            let study = StudyList()
            study.name = item._studyName
            study.studyPages = item.pages //This line has error

            studyList.append(study)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is making sense. It says that you are trying to assign an array of Page object to a variable that is defined as an array of StudyPage object.

From your code, you are loop though an array of Study object. You try to loop though each of them, create StudyList object out of it, and then append to another array to be displayed in a table view. 
From my guess, your StudyList class is defined like this

```
class StudyList :NSObject {
    var studyPages: [StudyPage]
}
```

And your Study class is defined like this

```
class Study :NSObject {
    var pages: [Page]
}
```

As you can see, in your for loop, you cannot just create a StudyList object and then assign an array of Page to its studyPages variable. In this case you need to either make them to be the same type, or have some sort of convertion between `Page` and `StudyPage`